# Line wrapping with prefix

Tags: wrapping

I'm using the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559061/emacs-how-to-keep-the-indentation-level-of-a-very-long-wrapped-line but can't make it do exactly what I want

If I have this long line of code:

```
if some_condition:
then
    some very long long long long long long long line
fi
```

With:

```
(add-hook 'visual-line-mode-hook 'adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode)
(visual-line-mode t)
```

it turns to:

```
if some_condition:
then
    some very long long long long long
    long long line
fi
```

but I would like this to turn to

```
if some_condition:
then
    some very long long long long long
    ... long long line
fi
```

This doesn't work:

```
(setq wrap-prefix "... ")
```

Comment: One option would be to use the built-in feature and customize the variable `adaptive-wrap-extra-indent`, but that will not add the ellipsis.  It would be necessary to modify the source code if a user wishes to see a leading ellipsis.  The extra indent (for wrapped lines subsequent to the first line) can be a positive or negative number or 0.  For more information about the aforementioned variable, type:  `M-x describe-variable RET adaptive-wrap-extra-indent RET`

Comment: The `adaptive-wrap` package is not built-in, but is available on GNU Elpa: https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/adaptive-wrap.html

Comment: `(setq adaptive-wrap-extra-indent 4)` does nothing for me..

Comment: I ended up hardcoding my elipsis in adaptive-wrap.el and now it works as I want.

Comment: @obadz Could you post the solution you found as an answer?